# Codeigniter's index.php appears after htaccess modification

Tags: php, codeigniter

So here's the thing, i've done the tutorial thing on CI, i have already done some modification in .htaccess to remove index.php in URL, in these case, when viewing records index.php doesn't appear, but when i try to create a new record, index.php suddenly appeared, i'm confused as to why it appeared, i've already done something to .htaccess like so,

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]
```

Here are some screenies,

**Viewing a record:** 
[image]

**Creating a new record:**
[image]

**After Creation:** 
[image]

Im confused as to why index.php suddenly appeared, i've already did some changes on .htaccess. am i missing something? please do share your inputs

**EDIT**
I just followed what they ask me to do on their user guide.

### Create a news item

```
<?php echo validation_errors(); ?>

<?php echo form_open('sample_controller/sample_create') ?>

    <label for="title">Title</label> 
    <input type="input" name="title" /><br />

    <label for="text">Text</label>  <textarea name="text"></textarea><br/>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Create news item" /> 

</form>
```

Comment: can you show us how you generated the link or redirect to that last scenario

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change `sample_controller/sample_create` to `/sample_controller/sample_create`

### update:

or @cballou answer updating the config will avoid the problem in the first place.

(in config/config.php set `$config['index_page'] = ''`)

Comment: yes yes this works, but what happen?, i still don't get why it appeared?

Comment: with htacces you told appache to route all requests to the index.php file but CI doesn't know about that so its trying to fix your urls... when you set the index_page to empty u r basically telling CI that there is no need for that

Comment: ohhh okie understood, though i really don't know anything about mod_rewrite but yeah i get what you mean.

Comment: in that case just the first couple of paragraphs here http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html should be doing wonders :)

Answer (score 0):

try `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [PT,L]` in place of

`RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]`

Answer (score 0):

I think the form action attribute contains the index.php segment. Htaccess isn't enough, edit your CodeIgniter configuration files too to remove.

Comment: yes i see it, there is this index.php on the action attribute, how do i configure this on my CI, it says here, in urls under user guide and also what @cballou said, that you should edit config.php but they didn't specify how

Answer (score 0):

CodeIgniter also requires you to also make adjustments to your `config/config.php` file to remove the default URL suffix of `index.php`. It's not highly mentioned in their guides as a necessity when discussing .htaccess.

[See documentation here](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/urls.html).

Comment: i don't get what you mean, is index.php considered a URL suffix or what?

Comment: scratch that last comment, i got what you mean, but their documentation didn't say anything on what to change in config.php

Comment: Yes to the first question. The vanilla install of CodeIgniter assumes you aren't using `.htaccess` and therefore defaults to `index.php` as the index page (URL suffix).